# How to handle permission denied when using fileutil::traverse

Tags: tcl

#### Problem

I am not a Tcl newbie and this problem baffles me. I want to traverse a directory tree and either handle or ignore those sub-directories or files which I have no permission to. Here is a small sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require fileutil::traverse

proc errorHandler {absPath errorMessage} {
    puts "ERROR: $absPath $errorMessage"
}

# Main
set searchDir /tmp
fileutil::traverse t $searchDir -errorcmd errorHandler

puts "\nFiles in $searchDir:"
t foreach fileName {
    puts $fileName
}
```

Output:

```
...
couldn't read directory "/tmp/launchd-56801.nzZRsA/": permission denied
    while executing
"glob -nocomplain -directory $current -types f          -- *"
    (procedure "GLOBF" line 2)
    invoked from within
"GLOBF $top"
    (procedure "::fileutil::traverse::Snit_methodnext" line 44)
    invoked from within
"$self next currentfile"
    (procedure "::fileutil::traverse::Snit_methodforeach" line 11)
    invoked from within
"t foreach fileName {
    puts $fileName
}"
    (file "./traverser1.tcl" line 17)
```

I know the problem: I don't have permission to read some of the sub-directories. That is why I put in the error handler per documentation. However, that error handler was never called. I suspect this is a bug in Tcl, but it could mean I misunderstood the documentation and did not use the package correct. I appreciate any help or suggestion to solve this problem.

#### My Environment

- Mac OS X Moutain Lion
- Tcl 8.5.9

#### Update

I looked at the source for `fileutil::traverse` for version 1.12 that comes with Mac OS X 10.8.4 Moutain Lion and version 1.15--the latest. What I found is:

```
method next {fvar} {
    # code ...
    if {![ACCESS $top]} {
        Error ...
        ...
```

But for for Tcl 8.4 or later, the implementation for ACCESS is:

```
proc ::fileutil::traverse::ACCESS {args} {return 1}
```

Whereas the implementation for Tcl 8.3 is:

```
proc ::fileutil::traverse::ACCESS {current} {
    if {[catch {
        set h [pwd] ; cd $current ; cd $h
    }]} {return 0}
    return 1
}
```

When I replaced the 8.4 version with 8.3 version, everything works. That tells me it is a bug in the code. I have no idea why that is the case.

Comment: Reading the docs, is the errorHandler proc supposed to return false?

Comment: I have tried both: returning False, then True. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work-around by adding a pre-filter, which attempt to cd into the directory and return True if the directory is accessible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require fileutil::traverse

# isAccessible: determines if the directory is accessible by attempting to cd into it
proc isAccessible {absPath} {
    set currentDir [pwd]
    if {[catch {cd $absPath}]} {
        set chdirOK False
    } else {
        set chdirOK True
    }
    cd $currentDir
    return $chdirOK
}

# Main
set searchDir /tmp
fileutil::traverse t $searchDir -prefilter isAccessible

puts "\nFiles in $searchDir:"
t foreach fileName {
    puts $fileName
}
```

#### Update

Donal's suggestion is a great one: it works, is short and sweet:

```
proc isAccessible {absPath} {
    return [file readable $absPath]
}
```

We can even do away with writing `isAccessible` altogether:

```
fileutil::traverse t $searchDir -prefilter "file readable"
```